# A3 cannot connect to assistant 2 for autopilot

Tags: dji-sdk, assistant

When I try I connect A3 to Assistant 2 for autopilot (v 2.0.3), nothing happens.
it connents fine when using Assistant 2 (v 1.2.5).

I tried both on windows 10 and osx. same problem.

A3 firmware version: 1.0.4.0

Comment: did you solve your problem? Which drone are you using?

Comment: I solved the problem, i was using A3-AG which is does not support the autopilot version of the Assistant software. The AG version does also not support usage of the API port. Either of these things are mentioned anywhere in DJI documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your drive doesn't work，you can check that in your Device manager.
In this case，you need to update your drive and the drive files directory is C:\Program Files\DJI Product\DJI Assistant 2\Drivers